# Android phone Work as a Recycle bin

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am new to Android Development.

[image]
My question is when we delete an item from the Android device. I want to
restore this item whatever we have deleted from the phone. Like Recycle Bin in
Computer. I am not able to follow this `BroadcastReceiever`flow.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is when we delete an item from the Android device.

There is concept of a generic "item" in Android, let alone deleting one.

> I am not able to follow this BroadcastReceieverflow.

That is because there are no broadcasts sent out related to delete operations.